# Calling other class methods from __new__() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have created a class `foo` as below:

```
class foo():

    def __new__(cls, a, b, c, add=True):
        return cls.sum(a, b, c) if add else cls.subtract(a, b, c)

    def sum(a, b, c):
        return a + b + c

    def subtract(a, b, c):
        return c - b - a

print(foo(1, 2, 3, True))
```

This program returns the required result as `6`. However, I needed to get the clarity of a few concepts:

1. Is using this methodology or design of OOP correct or is there a better way to do it? I want the class to return a value or any other object(not it's own class instance)
2. Regardless of the structure above, if `sum` and `subtract` are instance methods, how can they be called without instantiating an object as in the above example i.e., `print(...)`?

I have observed many python APIs and frameworks returning an object or a value through class instantiation.

I am trying to understand the core concepts of OOPs in python please help.

Comment: With `foo(1, 2, 3, True)` you *are* instantiating the object

Comment: however, while using PyCharm, it shows an error(during editing)... but it runs though. This made it confusing actually... Then I guess it's a faulty suggestion by PyCharm...

Comment: What error? Remember, PyCharm is trying to guess what will happen when the code actually runs without actually running it. From everything I read here, it doesn't do a great job.

Comment: Why is this a class? A function makes far more sense.

Comment: I agree. The error/suggestion is that it asks you to add `self` to `add` and `subtract` methods but when I add them, the program throws a `Missing Argument` error. This made me wonder whether `add` and `subtract` are instance methods.

Comment: @user2357112 as mentioned in the question I have observed that many APIs/framework where the class returns some value, so I was thinking of utilizing a similar structure... Please clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: Where have you observed this?

Comment: Like in Tensorflow `Conv2D` etc. are all classes apparently! But I am not sure if they are using the same structure or not. But the class take parameters and return objects

Comment: What, like tf.keras.layers.Conv2D? Calling that class returns an instance of Conv2D, like a normal class. Not an int.

Comment: oh ok. Concept Clarified. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now, `sum` and `subtract` are indeed instance methods.

```
>>> foo_obj = object.__new__(foo)  # This will actually create a foo object to demonstrate
>>> foo_obj.sum
<bound method foo.sum of <__main__.foo object at 0x0000000000000000>>
>>> type(foo_obj.sum)
<class 'method'>
```

But that's just because when you access them through an instance, Python dynamically creates a method (Basically just binds the first argument to the object, usually `self`)

But, you can access the wrapped function through the class:

```
>>> foo_obj.sum.__func__
<function foo.sum at 0x0000000000000001>
>>> foo.sum
<function foo.sum at 0x0000000000000001>
>>> foo_obj.sum.__func__ is foo.sum
True
```

So in your `__new__` function, it won't bind the first argument, and they call the underlying function instead of making them an instance method.

To fix the warnings, you can make them [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)s or [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)s. But it is generally bad practice to not return an object that is an instance of the class from the `__new__`. If you really wanted to use OOP, either subclass `int` or make a wrapper, so you can have:

```
>>> class Foo:
    __slots__ = 'value',
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, add=True):
        self.value = self.sum(a, b, c) if add else self.subtract(a, b, c)
    @staticmethod
    def sum(a, b, c):
        return a + b + c
    @staticmethod
    def subtract(a, b, c):
        return c - b - a
>>> foo = Foo(1, 2, 3, True)
>>> foo
<__main__.foo object at 0x0000000000000002>
>>> foo.value
6
```

or

```
>>> class Foo(int):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, a, b, c, add=True):
        value = cls.sum(a, b, c) if add else cls.subtract(a, b, c)
        return super().__new__(cls, value)
    @staticmethod
    def sum(a, b, c):
        return a + b + c
    @staticmethod
    def subtract(a, b, c):
        return c - b - a
>>> foo = Foo(1, 2, 3, True)
>>> foo
6
>>> type(foo)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```